# Determine which TLS Version is configured on AIX

Tags: ssl, aix, tls1.2

I am trying to API / DLL of an Terminal Emulator to write a code using which I can connect with an AIX or other UNIX boxes and pass some commands.

I am finding it difficult to determine how to check which protocol does the server uses SSLv3, TLS1.0, TLS1.1 or TLS1.2

If I am able to find this I will be able to pass relevant parameters to the function and connect.

Please suggest if anyone has any Idea on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Most likely it is SSHv2

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to test your server with openssl commands. For example :

```
openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect serverip:443
```

You also have -tls1 -tls1_1 -tls1_2 parameters.

Comment: What if the port 443 is not listing? Will this command still work?

Comment: Of course not. You want to test a server which is listening on some port, and usually it is 443 although it could be almost anything else. It's impossible to test something that's not running, do you agree ?

Comment: Off: Since when does httpd execute shell-commands? (That's what OP wishes to achieve.)

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond : Since at least CGI-BIN implementation which is mentioned in the Apache 0.8.3 change log, 1995. But anyway, the question doesn't mention any httpd use, and it's asking for any idea.